# Pass entire Model."List" to another action in the same controller (from view)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I really have no clue on how to do this...

I'm trying to pass my entire Model."List" to another action in my controller.

(The list that I'm trying to pass is the  IEnumerable < Client > Results)

The view model:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Pesquisa")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessageResourceName = "MinLengthErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages))]
    public string Query { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Página")]
    public int? Page { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tamanho da Página")]
    public int? PageSize { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Total de Páginas")]
    public int TotalPages { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Resultados")]
    public IEnumerable<Client> Results { get; set; }

    public PagerViewModel ToPagerViewModel()
    {
        return new PagerViewModel()
        {
            Page = this.Page.GetValueOrDefault(1),
            PageSize = this.PageSize.GetValueOrDefault(20),
            TotalPages = this.TotalPages
        };
    }
}
```

The view

```
@model EFGEREN.App.Models.ViewModels.Clients.IndexViewModel
@using System.Linq
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@using EFGEREN.App.Models.Contexts
@using EFGEREN.App.Models.Entities
@using EFGEREN.App.Models.Entities
@using Resources

@Html.ActionLink("Export lista de emails CSV", "ExportClientsListToCSV", Model.Results)

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>@("Código")</th>
        <th>@("Informações Gerais")</th>
        <th>@("Endereço")</th>
        <th>@("Contato")</th>
        <th>@("Cliente desde")</th>
        <th>@("Última atividade")</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Results.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName))
    {
        <tr>
            //showing my data here... As its a lot of things I just omited it
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Here is how I populate my viewmodel:

```
        public ActionResult Index([Bind(Include = "Query,Page,PageSize")] IndexViewModel input)
    {
        var trimmedQuery = (input.Query ?? string.Empty)
            .TrimStart(new[] { ' ', '0', '.', ',' })
            .Trim();

        var query = db.Clients as IQueryable<Client>;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(trimmedQuery))
            query = query.Where(client => (
                (client.IsDeleted == false) && (
                    (client.Id.ToString().Contains(trimmedQuery)) ||
                    (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(client.OfficialName) && client.OfficialName.ToLower().Contains(trimmedQuery)) ||
                    (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(client.DisplayName) && client.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(trimmedQuery)) 
                )
            ));

        var currentUserName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        if (!User.IsInRole("Master") && !User.IsInRole("Manager"))
            query = query.Where(results => (results.AssignedToLogin == currentUserName)&&
                                           (results.IsDeleted==false));

        var paging = input.ToPagerViewModel();
        var pageIndex = (paging.Page - 1);
        input.TotalPages = query.Count() / paging.PageSize;
        input.Results = query
            .OrderBy(d => d.DisplayName)
            .Skip(paging.PageSize * pageIndex)
            .Take(paging.PageSize)
            .ToArray();

        return View(input);
    }
```

And the actionresult that will receive it:

```
 public void ExportClientsListToCSV(IEnumerable<Client> Results)
    {
    //do something
    }
```

As you can see, I tried using and ActionLink in my view to pass the data, but my action always get a null "Results"...

I'm new to C#, so I may be missing something that may be obvious to you...

I appreciate any help, and thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot pass a collection of complex objects using ActionLink (look at the href attribute of the html you generating to understand) and nor would you ever want to. Apart from the ugly query string, it could easily exceed the query string limit and throw an exception. But what would be the point of passing back the unaltered collection to the server anyway - just get the collection again in the controller.

Comment: Hello Stephen, thank you for your comment. When you say " just get the collection again in the controller." How can I achieve this? My collection is populated in the Index and I want to use it in another Actionresult. Thank you for your time.

Comment: In exactly the same way you got the collection in the `Index()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid passing in the entire list of clients and just pass in limited information to re-obtain the collection from the database. If you must pass the information without reobtaining the information (performance reasons). You'd need to build the url yourself and end up with something like this. `../ExportClientsListToCSV?clientids[0]=42&clientids[1]=624&clientids[2]=5‌​662&clientids[3]=666`

However be aware there is a length on the maximum length of a URL, and this would ONLY include clients on the current page. If that's the intended behavior, I'd just pass in the same filters (query, page size and page number).

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export lista de emails CSV", "ExportClientsListToCSV", new {Model.Results.query, Model.Results.Page, Model.Results.PageSize})
```

However It's more likely you want to export ALL clients that match your query to a CSV file so why not only pass the query string?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export lista de emails CSV", "ExportClientsListToCSV", new {Model.Results.query})
```

**Unrelated Note:**
On a note unrelated to your question, you can clean up the multiple using statements inside of your view by including the namespaces inside of the web.config in your `Views` folder.

for example...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- config sections -->
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, [version info]" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

        <add namespace="System.Linq" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
        <add namespace="EFGEREN.App.Models.ViewModels" />
        <add namespace="EFGEREN.App.Models.Contexts" />
        <add namespace="EFGEREN.App.Models.Entities" />
        <add namespace="EFGEREN.App.Models.Entities" />
        <add namespace="Resources" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
<!-- Other sections here -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: This cannot work - its generates `href="../ExportClientsListToCSV?clientIds=System.Collections.IEnumerable[int]"` You cannot pass a any collection using `ActionLink`

Comment: No, it can be done. I just wasn't aware there is no native method for serializing an object to a QueryString in MVC. I've done it in javascript I've just never had the need to do it in C#, I assumed it would handle it implicitly. Basically you'd end up with a URL similar to this. `href="../ExportClientsListToCSV?clientids[0]=42&clientids[1]=624&clientids[2]=5662&clientids[3]=666`

Comment: My comment was that it cannot be done using `ActionLink()` (which it can't)

Comment: Oh, absolutely. You're right, the `ActionLink` method is pretty limited in that regard. I made the assumption that it would handle it natively, which after your comment and some testing of my own, discovered that it can't. I just meant to show that it's only the native URL generation that is limited, not the ability to receive collections in the query string :-)

Comment: Internally `ActionLink()` (and all the other methods that generate route values) use the `.ToString()` method of each property to generate the route value dictionary (there is no recursion). And for good reason. If the property is a collection, there would be a very good chance that the query string limit would be exceeded and an exception would be thrown. In OP's case there is no point sensing anything. The correct approach is just to get the collection again in the other method.

Comment: Agreed, I've updated my answer to give a better example and removed the previous suggestion to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding some of the concepts. It has less to do with C# and more with how you'd want to pass data around in the Web/stateless environment.

The easiest way to do this includes a few modifications to your original approach:

1. Include an "export" parameter to the Index action and default it to "false".
2. Modify your action logic to return different ActionResults based on the parameter. If it's false, return the View() otherwise return the action result that ends up exporting the items
3. In the actual view, change the action link so it recreates the same url with the export=true flag.

Once that's done, think about refactoring the main action for better maintainability.